# How can I mirror weight painting?

Tags: mirror, weight-painting

How can I mirror my weight painting to the opposed side of my character? I know that there is Mirror function, but it doesn't assign the weight to bones on the opposed side. Can I do it manually?

[image]

Comment: You find more details one mirror editing here:http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Advanced_Animation/Guided_tour/Armature/edit

Comment: I watched your link, it is about rigging, but I need mirror skinning. I also know that there is X-mirror, but it simply copy my weight to counter side, but to same bone. It looks that Blender don`t have this function.

Comment: It has. You need to follow a naming convention for it to work. Each pair of bones need to have the same name with the suffix .L for the left side and .R for the right side. E.g. UpperArm.L and UpperArm.R. In the weighting Options of the tool panel turn on "X Mirror". You dont need a mirror modifier for it to work. See [http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Rigging/Armatures/Editing/Properties](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Rigging/Armatures/Editing/Properties) and look for "Naming Conventions"

Comment: Some will also find useful [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16504/is-there-any-way-to-copy-the-weight-of-one-bone-over-to-anotherforgot-to-use-x)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each pair of bones need to have the same name with the suffix .L for the left side and .R for the right side. E.g. UpperArm.L and UpperArm.R. In the weighting Options of the tool panel turn on "X Mirror".

Comment: Is there a way to do this after the weights have been painted?

Answer (score 7):

The mirror modifier takes weights into account:

[image]

[image]

In [*Weight Paint*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Vertex_Groups/Weight_Paint) mode you can edit the weights they would be applied symmetrically.

Comment: This is working for one bone, but I need mirror skin to opposed side, so there is another bone, not same.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, Stacker, for the tip! As long as the mirror modifier is FIRST in the chain, you can edit vertex weights however you like and have the result mirrored perfectly. It even mirrors manually assigned weights to individual vertices! This in particular is not possible without the modifier, as only weights "painted" by a brush would respect the built-in X-Axis mirror feature, and not weights assigned manually in the Vertex Groups list. In that case, you would have to mirror the vertex group, which is tedious for many changes. So for ultimate mirroring, use the modifier! :-)

Answer (score 7):

1. Select your object then select vertex group
   [image]
2. Select group you want to edit
3. Click the dark down_arrow to its right

[image]

4. *Copy Vertex Group*
5. Then click on the same down_arrow and *Mirror* the original of your
   vertex group

[image]

6. Last step delete the original then select copy and rename it to
   original.

[image]

Comment: A suggestion would be to rename the copy to ".R", so you don't have to delete the original ".L" group. So copy "shoulder.L" (making "shoulder.L_copy"), mirror the copy, delete the preexisting "shoulder.R" if it exists and then rename the mirrored group to "shoulder.R" so it takes its place.

Answer (score 1):

"This is working for one bone, but I need mirror skin to opposed side, so there is another bone, not same. "

In my experience the mirrior modifier won't create vertex groups for you. If you have a vertex group named Arm_Right you need to add a new vertex group and name it Arm_Left before you use the mirror modifier.