# Is there any way to copy the weight of one bone over to another(forgot to use x-mirror)?

Tags: rigging

I solved my other problem and I finally got it to deform to an acceptable level. However now I'm having trouble, I forgot to activate x-mirror when weight painting and I got the weights right on one side but I can't or don't know how I can transfer it over to the other side. I want to transfer the weight of thigh.L to thigh.R so is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 14):

I'll show you the method that works for me.

1. Activate the **'corrective shapekeys'** addon (file--> user preferences--> addons--> corrective shapekeys). It can be reached from the 'object data' menu (under the 'vertex groups' header) by clicking the black 'down arrow'.

[image]

2. In 'weight paint mode' select the bone with the assigned weight and click **'copy vertex group'** in the corective shapekeys addon menu.

[image]

3. Now you have a *thigh.L* and the *thigh.L_copy* in 'vertex groups'. With the original one selected, click on the padlock icon and lock it. Next select the copy and click the **'mirror vertex groups (topology)'** option.

[image]

4. Rename the *thigh.L_copy* to *thigh.R*.

[image]

5. Now clicking the bone on the left and then the bone on the right, you can see that both have individual weights assigned to them.

[image]

6. The last thing is to assign the proper vertex groups to *thigh.R* bone. Select *thigh.R* bone and enter the 'edit mode' (TAB). Press A key to deselect everything and then press 'select' under 'vertex groups'. As you can see the right bone has assigned vertices that belong to the left one. We have to to remove it.

[image]

7. Unselect (B + mouse scroll) the vertices from the right side.

[image]

8. Remove the vertices from the left side by pressing 'remove' under 'vertex groups'.

[image]

9. Press A to deselect all and pres 'select' again. Now only the right side vertices are assigned to the right bone.

[image]

The left side weights and assigned vertices have been transfered to the right side.

Comment: This is horrible. 

This is like owning a sewing machine and someone asks how to sew a line and the only answer is to take a needle and thread... Where is the button? The mirror skin weights transfer button? Just because it is free doesn't mean we have to pay with endless tedium.

Comment: For some reason this works perfectly for me even without steps 5-9. I mean all I have to do is choose a bone in WP mode, copy its group, mirror it and rename it. That's it. All done in Wieght Paint mode. Literally , a matter of couple of clicks. I use v. 2.78.

Comment: This isn't going to work for me because I am using the same armature to control the body and deform the clothes