# Mirror vertex groups

Tags: armature, weight-painting, mirror, vertex-groups

I have already weight painted and assigned geometry to the left half of my model. I would like to copy thee contents to the right half of the model. How do I this?

[image]

[**.blend file**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33515)

Comment: Please see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16504/is-there-any-way-to-copy-the-weight-of-one-bone-over-to-anotherforgot-to-use-x

Answer (score 4):

Go to the vertex group panel and choose Copy Vertex Group (from the drop down menu) for each group you want to mirror. Then select the copy and choose Mirror Vertex Group.

Comment: I tried that, and I get this error:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/236590267791048706/419289112814551060/unknown.png