# Symmetrize Vertex Group on object with armature

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have an object with an armature and I want the limbs on both sides to be symmetrical.

I rigged the object using Mixamo's autorigger because it performs much better than blender could. However the Vertex weights are not symmetrical. In fact: on the left limbs I can see some vertex distortions and the limbs on the left side are bending a bit differently than the right limbs.

I know it's due to the Vertex weight because I can clearly see it in "Weight Paint" mode. The limbs on the right side are perfect! Is there a way how I can copy all vertex groups which define the weightings on the right side and apply them to the left side of the limbs (with their own vertex group name for the left limbs)?

Don't worry, the object is symmetrical and the bones that were created by Mixamo are also symmetrical so I just need to make the weights also symmetrical.

Comment: A google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=Blender+Symmetrize+Vertex+Group leads to first result: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21350/mirror-vertex-groups which leads to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16504/is-there-any-way-to-copy-the-weight-of-one-bone-over-to-anotherforgot-to-use-x.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was searching for this but I guess I wasn't searching right. You can flag this as a duplicate. I promise that I won't do that again. Anyway thank you for the help.

Comment: No harm done, duplicates are fine, they help people who ask the problem differently. By writing this you created another path to solution, I am sure it will help someone. I showed how I got to the answer and what query I used, the pattern is similar for other searches and usually gives me what I want. By reading it back I realize I should have phrase it with some words around to be not as instructional, it leaves an impression you did something bad.