# Re-mirror weights for whole character

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I have a character setup with proper .L and .R ending vertex groups. I have been making weight changes to one side of the character, but now have found that I left X-mirror off for some of them. I know that I can manually mirror any given group through the vertex groups panel, but I need to re-mirror 20+ groups. Is there a way to mirror all .L groups to .R properly?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16504/is-there-any-way-to-copy-the-weight-of-one-bone-over-to-anotherforgot-to-use-x

Comment: Yes, that is the method I meant. But that's manually one group at a time.