# Mirror Armature problem

Tags: rigging, armature, mirror

So, I'm trying to make a model for a Minecraft mod. When I try to move the legs, they both move at the same time. It has something to do with the mirror. How do I fix this? I tried looking it up, but all the times I've tried none seem to work.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/140155/49553

Comment: I try fixing the weight, but it only mirrors it on the other side. I want to keep the mirror (cause that's how I sculpted it) but make it so that the armature won't duplicate it on the other side. Is there another way I can get the other side the same, without the armature mirroring the same thing on the other side?

Comment: May I ask why you don't want the armature to be symmetrical? Your character is and I would assume you want to move both sides independantly.