# Blender finger weighting problem

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I'm trying to rig a character but one of the gloves won't rig properly: instead of following the finer the bone is on it follows the finger that is next to it how do I fix this?

[image]

I have the rig here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't exactly understand what bone part is not following what instead of what, but I checked your file and R and L gloves are weighted completely different... if one glove behaves well, you should apply the same weights (eg see [How can I mirror weight painting?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9390/how-can-i-mirror-weight-painting) or [Is there any way to copy the weight of one bone over to another(forgot to use x-mirror)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16504/is-there-any-way-to-copy-the-weight-of-one-bone-over-to-anotherforgot-to-use-x))

Here is the comparison I did (I had to open twice your file in two different blender instances aside)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]