# how to use "Mirror Vertex Location & Weight" script?

Tags: weight-painting

I would like to know how to mirror skin weight from left to right.
[image]
I have prepared symmetrical bones and did paint weight only left side,

.

And run the script called "Mirror Vertex Location & Weight" in edit mode as selecting all the left vertices.
Then I got syntax error in picture below...
[image]

I would like to get advice about how you do mirroring all the weight at once..

like "mirror skin weight" in maya.
[image]

thank you

Comment: Replace `&gt;` by  `!=` or `==` in line 22 (I'm not sure which one is correct here)

Comment: thank you for the advice Gorgious, it helped but got new many errors from other lines,, maybe this script is old for current version.. but thank you very much.

Comment: You should try the mirror modifier. : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9392/86891 Tell me if you can't get it to work, I'll post an updated answer

Comment: thank you , I read the page. I thought it is useful if i use a couple of bones.  when I have arm1 arm2 arm3...etc, its bit complicated. I found this page,, https://blenderartists.org/t/copy-and-mirror-weight-vertex/556790/11      the script written by mathiasA  in Dec 2012(which is at middle part of the long page.)   It worked to mirror all vertex group at once.

Comment: Oh Okay you only want to mirror some vertex groups, not all. You can either add the errors in your question so I can try to troubelshoot it or add the code so I can see by myself because the python API has changed in Blender since 2012

Comment: yes I mean I want to mirror all vertex group.  and yes about API,,I got lot error saying "no module named Blender".  –