# Is there a way to mirror/symmetrize weight paint?

Tags: armature, weight-painting

How can I apply one part of the weight paint on the other side of the mesh with symmetrized bones?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9390/how-can-i-mirror-weight-painting

Comment: Here's how to solve this if you are bad at this like me. Do your weight painting, then select the vertex group you want to carry over. Do in order, copy vertex group, mirror vertex group, change name accordingly to other side, ie shoulder.L -> shoulder.R. If there are problems you can go back to edit mode, select the vertices and do Symmetrize(mesh dropdown menu) because mirror needs exact same mirrored vertices. Some vertices might still cause problems go remove those from VG and either blur or paint the broken parts on your new vertex group.