# How to remove mirrored weight painting only?

Tags: weight-painting, mirror

At some point I achieved it with the foot (image 1). Now I cannot seem to remember how I did this; I cannot find where the option is to turn off the mirroring for weight painting only and continue to have the geometry mirrored and not yet applied (image 2).

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Probably it's impossible with a mirror modifier, because the mirrored verts are not exist, so you can't assign independent weightdata for them.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at my vertex groups and I at one point must have made a right foot variant before I had removed the bones from the right side. I will remove the right vertex groups, symmetrize the bones, then go from here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9390/how-can-i-mirror-weight-painting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at my vertex groups and I at one point must have made a right foot variant before I had removed the bones from the right side. I will remove the right vertex groups, symmetrize the bones, then go from here: [How can I mirror weight painting?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9390/how-can-i-mirror-weight-painting)

Unless there is an easier solution that is posted.